# How can I center the input box in my coded calculator?

Tags: python, tkinter, geometry, calculator, python-3.7

I'm trying to code a little basic calculator in Tkinter using Python 3.7.2. Nothing too special, but I keep running into the same problem: I cannot for the love of Jesus move the input bar so that it is above ALL the input buttons / the first row. I tried putting it in the different columns or using other versions of the code like `geometry` but absolutely nothing has worked. I also posed the question on the (german) Q&A-Site [Gutefrage](https://www.gutefrage.net/frage/python-tkinter-textbox-ueber-knoepfe-platzieren) but there don't seem to be many programmers / the answers were a little bit unclear. Any ideas on how to do this?

Here's my code (WIP):

````
from random import *
from math import *

def insert_1():
    text.insert(END, "1")
def insert_2():
    text.insert(END, "2")
def insert_3():
    text.insert(END, "3")
def insert_4():
    text.insert(END, "4")
def insert_5():
    text.insert(END, "5")
def insert_6():
    text.insert(END, "6")
def insert_7():
    text.insert(END, "7")
def insert_8():
    text.insert(END, "8")
def insert_9():
    text.insert(END, "9")
def insert_plus():
    text.insert(END, "+")
def insert_minus():
    text.insert(END, "-")
def insert_divide():
    text.insert(END, ":")
def insert_multiply():
    text.insert(END, "*")
def insert_ac():
    text.delete(0.0, END)
def insert_equals():
    text.delete(0.0, END)
    text.insert(END, "Calculating...")


calculator = Tk()

text = Text(calculator, width=20, height=1)
bu1 = Button(calculator, text="1", activeforeground="white", activebackground="grey", command=insert_1)
bu2 = Button(calculator, text="2", activeforeground="white", activebackground="grey", command=insert_2)
bu3 = Button(calculator, text="3", activeforeground="white", activebackground="grey", command=insert_3)
bu4 = Button(calculator, text="4", activeforeground="white", activebackground="grey", command=insert_4)
bu5 = Button(calculator, text="5", activeforeground="white", activebackground="grey", command=insert_5)
bu6 = Button(calculator, text="6", activeforeground="white", activebackground="grey", command=insert_6)
bu7 = Button(calculator, text="7", activeforeground="white", activebackground="grey", command=insert_7)
bu8 = Button(calculator, text="8", activeforeground="white", activebackground="grey", command=insert_8)
bu9 = Button(calculator, text="9", activeforeground="white", activebackground="grey", command=insert_9)
bu_ac = Button(calculator, text="AC", activeforeground="white", activebackground="grey", command=insert_ac)
bu_plus = Button(calculator, text="+", activeforeground="white", activebackground="grey", command=insert_plus)
bu_minus = Button(calculator, text="-", activeforeground="white", activebackground="grey", command=insert_minus)
bu_divide = Button(calculator, text=":", activeforeground="white", activebackground="grey", command=insert_divide)
bu_multiply = Button(calculator, text="x", activeforeground="white", activebackground="grey", command=insert_multiply)
bu_equals = Button(calculator, text="=", activeforeground="white", activebackground="grey", command=insert_equals)





text.grid(row=1)
bu1.grid(row=2, column=1)
bu2.grid(row=2, column=2)
bu3.grid(row=2, column=3)
bu4.grid(row=3, column=1)
bu5.grid(row=3, column=2)
bu6.grid(row=3, column=3)
bu7.grid(row=4, column=1)
bu8.grid(row=4, column=2)
bu9.grid(row=4, column=3)
bu_plus.grid(row=2, column=4)
bu_minus.grid(row=3, column=4)
bu_divide.grid(row=4, column=4)
bu_multiply.grid(row=2, column=5)
bu_ac.grid(row=3, column=5)
bu_equals.grid(row=4, column=5)```
````

Comment: If the Text is to appear above all of the buttons, in their various columns, then it has to have `column=` and `columnspan=` options that include *all* of those columns.

Comment: here's a tip: `insert = lambda x: text.insert(END, x)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two separate frames and put one in the top of the other

I created the fc and fc2 and put the fc on top of the fc2

```
from random import *
from math import *
from tkinter import *

def insert_1():
    text.insert(END, "1")
def insert_2():
    text.insert(END, "2")
def insert_3():
    text.insert(END, "3")
def insert_4():
    text.insert(END, "4")
def insert_5():
    text.insert(END, "5")
def insert_6():
    text.insert(END, "6")
def insert_7():
    text.insert(END, "7")
def insert_8():
    text.insert(END, "8")
def insert_9():
    text.insert(END, "9")
def insert_plus():
    text.insert(END, "+")
def insert_minus():
    text.insert(END, "-")
def insert_divide():
    text.insert(END, ":")
def insert_multiply():
    text.insert(END, "*")
def insert_ac():
    text.delete(0.0, END)
def insert_equals():
    text.delete(0.0, END)
    text.insert(END, "Calculating...")


calculator = Tk()
fc = Frame(calculator)
fc.grid(row=1)
fc2  = Frame(calculator)
fc2.grid(row = 2)
text = Text(fc, width=20, height=1)
bu1 = Button(fc2, text="1", activeforeground="white", activebackground="grey", command=insert_1)
bu2 = Button(fc2, text="2", activeforeground="white", activebackground="grey", command=insert_2)
bu3 = Button(fc2, text="3", activeforeground="white", activebackground="grey", command=insert_3)
bu4 = Button(fc2, text="4", activeforeground="white", activebackground="grey", command=insert_4)
bu5 = Button(fc2, text="5", activeforeground="white", activebackground="grey", command=insert_5)
bu6 = Button(fc2, text="6", activeforeground="white", activebackground="grey", command=insert_6)
bu7 = Button(fc2, text="7", activeforeground="white", activebackground="grey", command=insert_7)
bu8 = Button(fc2, text="8", activeforeground="white", activebackground="grey", command=insert_8)
bu9 = Button(fc2, text="9", activeforeground="white", activebackground="grey", command=insert_9)
bu_ac = Button(fc2, text="AC", activeforeground="white", activebackground="grey", command=insert_ac)
bu_plus = Button(fc2, text="+", activeforeground="white", activebackground="grey", command=insert_plus)
bu_minus = Button(fc2, text="-", activeforeground="white", activebackground="grey", command=insert_minus)
bu_divide = Button(fc2, text=":", activeforeground="white", activebackground="grey", command=insert_divide)
bu_multiply = Button(fc2, text="x", activeforeground="white", activebackground="grey", command=insert_multiply)
bu_equals = Button(fc2, text="=", activeforeground="white", activebackground="grey", command=insert_equals)





text.grid(row = 1)
bu1.grid(row=2, column=1)
bu2.grid(row=2, column=2)
bu3.grid(row=2, column=3)
bu4.grid(row=3, column=1)
bu5.grid(row=3, column=2)
bu6.grid(row=3, column=3)
bu7.grid(row=4, column=1)
bu8.grid(row=4, column=2)
bu9.grid(row=4, column=3)
bu_plus.grid(row=2, column=4)
bu_minus.grid(row=3, column=4)
bu_divide.grid(row=4, column=4)
bu_multiply.grid(row=2, column=5)
bu_ac.grid(row=3, column=5)
bu_equals.grid(row=4, column=5)
```